# Appendices formatting/ Text displayed by reference

Tags: formatting, appendices

I want to obtain toc and text formatting as shown in MWE.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{polish}
 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

 \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
    \@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~\@cftasnumb%
 }

\begin{document}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section 1}
bla bla \ref{app2} bla.

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\newpage

\appendix
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}

    \section*{Appendices}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Appendix \Alph{subsection}.}
    \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{subsection}}

    \subsection{Description.}
    \label{app1}

    \subsection{Description.}
    \label{app2}

\end{document}
```

But in section 1, I don't want to get "bla bla Appendix B. bla.", but: "bla bla B bla."
(In polish due to declination I can't use header "Appendix B" in text.)

So, to solve my problem I can find how to:

1. get only number from Appendix.
2. make header "Appendix X. Description." without using:

```
 \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Appendix \Alph{subsection}.}
```

In both ways I failed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Also, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Again, welcome!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me. I will adapt and won't make such mistakes again.

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as a mistake. It is just the way things are done here. You will get used to it after a while. Enjoy the community. `:)` Once again, welcome!

Comment: Up to this point, I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve here. Can you make your question clearer or, better yet, post a picture that shows what you try to achieve?